# What is this children's story about an inventor and son who live underground and fight rich men who hunt living cheese?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this book around 15 years ago.

The main character of the story is a young boy and his (I think adopted) father, who live underground. The boy goes above ground at night to scavenge food. I believe he used a pair of mechanical wings to fly around. At one point he is chased, and in the escape his wings break.

The main antagonists are a group who hunt living cheese, which run around with arms and legs. The inventor used to be involved with them before he was forced to live underground.

They also encounter talking rats, and at the end of the book, one rat is fed cheese until he grows extremely large, and eventually explodes, covering the town in cheese.

Comment: Not http://falsemachine.blogspot.com/2020/10/the-zolimko.html although that did pop up on searches.

Comment: I have closed your question as a Duplicate, but that does not mean it is a bad question. It is merely one we have answered before (a few times), and this helps tie them together in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Here Be Monsters!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Be_Monsters!)* by Alan Snow matches on several points.

[image: Front cover of Here Be Monsters!]

> Protagonist Arthur lives with his adoptive grandfather, William, in the complex network of tunnels beneath Ratbridge, where William hides after unjustly accused of attempted murder. Arthur emerges at sundown in search of food, aided by a pair of hand-cranked mechanical wings. He also carries a doll—an effigy of his grandfather with wings—which serves as a walkie-talkie, allowing him to communicate with his grandfather. On one such expedition, Arthur witnesses an illegal cheese hunt, and follows the hunters and the captured cheeses back to the Cheese Hall. Arthur's wings are stolen, and he is almost captured, by Archibald Snatcher, the leader of the once-powerful Cheese Guild. Arthur is rescued by Fish, a boxtroll, who takes Arthur to Willbury Nibble, the proprietor of a former pet shop called 'Here Be Monsters'. He shares his home with several boxtrolls (Shoe, Egg, and Fish) and a cabbagehead (Titus). Such creatures usually live underground and are collectively termed Underlings. Arthur's new friends intend to help him return to his grandfather, but quickly discover that all of the entrances to the tunnels have been sealed.

> .... A gigantic rat emerges from a pit in the middle of the floor, which the Laundry recognise as one of their missing comrades. Snatcher reveals that the Guild has been transferring the size of captured Underlings to "the Great One", and feeding him with the captured cheeses, to wreak vengeance on Ratbridge. Still believing her a boxtroll, the Guild transfers Marjorie's size to the rat, leaving her only seven inches tall. Arthur is then brought into the lab; but Herbert frees the captives and knocks a hole in the wall to allow their escape. Arthur again retrieves his wings—and Marjorie's prototype—and the group returns to the ship.
>
> The Guild dress the Great One in armour; and the heroes return to the Cheese Hall to stop him. They activate a large electromagnet, which draws the iron armour toward the hall; whereupon the Great One explodes, covering the town in a layer of cheese....

The book was later adapted to the film, *[The Boxtrolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boxtrolls)*

Comment: This is definitely it, thank you!

Comment: Not at all. The hunting of cheese, and the mechanical wings, were details that stuck out in my head.